Nginx open socket left in connection issue
With an increase in the load on my server, I started seeing errors like open socket # left in connection 5 followed by a restart of nginx after multiple such errors.
I read a lot about it, checked the worker_connections which is 1k, checked limits, which are set to 1048576, also I checked the limit of nginx using cat /proc/{nginx_proc_pid}/limits, and value is the same as a ulimits. worker_processes set to auto. I'm using nginx with php-fpm (with FastCGI)inside of k8s with HPA enabled, which can scale up to 15 instances (default value is 4 instances) set to scale if more than 60% of memory or CPU is used.
I see those errors happening only after responses with 499 status code, but not on each 499 response.
My timeouts are 60 seconds on the Nginx side and the same set on the FPM side. I do not know where else to look :( Thank you so much for your attention and participation!
